# Android hint style

Tags: android

I want a style that makes my `TextView` look exactly the same as a hint in a `EditText`. Something like this:

```
<style name="HintStyle" parent="TextViewStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/hint_color</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.02</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">1sp</item>
</style>
```

Or is there one that already exists so that I can directly apply it on my `TextView`?

Comment: hintTextcolor attribute in textview